# Java simbolo grado celsius º

Tags: java, unicode

Tengo un progama Java desarrollado con Netbeans que crea un archivo con string. Si lo ejecuto desde Netbeans el simbolo º (simbolo de grados celsius) lo crea como Åº y si creo el .jar y ejecuto el mismo programa lo crea como un espacio y º.
Necesito que el .jar lo cree como Åº para que lo pueda leer otro programa .
¿que puedo hacer?
No lo guardo como .txt, el programa de java crea el archivo en formato .fco. Si lo abro con WordPad veo el error pero desde el note++ ni lo veia. introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí Si ejecuto el programa desde Netbeans me crea el archivo con todo bien pero si creo el .jar es cuando este simbolo lo crea de manera diferente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo :

```
File f;       
f = new File(nombreArchivo);

System.out.println("Desde acceso :"+rut);
numHojas= getnumHojas(rut);  

//Escritura
try{
FileWriter w = new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(w);
PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(bw);  
wr.write(basDatos.getCabecera());//escribimos en el archivo
basDatos.getCabecera()
```

No es una base de datos, es una clase donde tengo un string simplemente y lo llamo base de datos para normalizar mi forma de hacer los programas.

```
cabecera="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?>\n" +
        //"<formcontrol angle-unit=\"°\" dist-unit=\"mm\" expanded=\"1\" fc-version=\"4.4.22\" ignore-projection=\"0\">\n" +
         "<formcontrol angle-unit=\""+" \u00b0"+"\" dist-unit=\"mm\" expanded=\"1\" fc-version=\"4.4.22\" ignore-projection=\"0\">\n" +
        "\n" +
```

Al final lo consegui gracias a esta página:
https://unicode-table.com/es/#basic-latin

Me sigue saliendo diferente desde la interfaz de netbeans y el jar pero consegui que funcionara

Comment: El problema es que el `encoding` con el que `WordPad` abre y guarda todos los archivos es `Unicode` (_y hasta donde yo se, no se puede cambiar_). Te recomiendo que utilices, por ejemplo, `NotePad`, el cual te permite abrir/guardar archivos y seleccionar el `encoding`.

Comment: El problema me surgio por que el archivo que creo yo lo lee otro programa y siempre habia hecho pruebas con lo que me salia de Netbeans pero al crear el .jar vi esto. Con el note++no lo ves pero te das cuenta que tiene un bit mas.

Comment: @Marcos notepad no permite cambiar el encoding de un archivo. Quizás te refieres a Notepad++

Comment: Tengo un programa en Java que crea un archivo. Cuando lo ejecuto desde Netbenas me crea el simbolo º de una manera y cuando ejecuto el mismo programa desde el .jar (creado desde Netbeans) el simbolo º me lo crea de otra manera diferente. Necesito que el .jar me lo cree el archivo igual que me lo crea desde Netbeans.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ, en `Windows 10` el `Notepad`, [permite seleccionar el `encoding`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYN0Q.png), tanto para abrir [como para guardar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmqqf.png)

Comment: Ves una Â porque abres el archivo con una codificación diferente, probablemente ASCII. El caracter ° en UTF-8 [ocupa 2 bytes](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm) (0xC2 0xB0). En ASCII cada byte corresponde exactamente a un carácter, y casualmente, 0xC2 en ASCII corresponde a la Â.

Answer (score 0):

Es difícil ayudarte con la poca información que ofreces. ¿De dónde coge los datos tu programa para llevarlos al fichero? La consola que ofrece Netbeans es distinta a la del sistema (Para que falle en el sistema pero funcione en el IDE tal y como dices).

Es probable que en algún punto de tu programa la codificación de caracteres se altere y cambie ofreciendo un caracter que no corresponde. Mediante algún  InputStreamReader o  OutputStreamWriter tienen un método llamado `.getEncoding();`que también puede ayudarte a saber cuál codificación de caracteres estás empleando. También puedes ver cual es la codificación medainte el uso de la propiedad System "file.encoding" de Java mediante ***file.encoding*** y también mediante el uso de la variable de entorno ***"JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS"***.

Vease un ejemplo:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class CharacterEncodingExample {

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    String defaultCharacterEncoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding"); // Obtiene la codificación de caracteres.
    System.out.println("defaultCharacterEncoding por propiedad: " + defaultCharacterEncoding);
    System.out.println("defaultCharacterEncoding por el código: " + getDefaultCharEncoding());
    System.out.println("defaultCharacterEncoding por el charSet: " + Charset.defaultCharset());

    System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-16");

    System.out.println("defaultCharacterEncoding por propiedad después de actualizar file.encoding : " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));

    System.out.println("defaultCharacterEncoding por código después de actualizar file.encoding : " + getDefaultCharEncoding());

    System.out.println("defaultCharacterEncoding por java.nio.Charset after updating file.encoding : " + Charset.defaultCharset());

}

public static String getDefaultCharEncoding(){
    byte [] bArray = {'w'};
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArray);
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    String defaultCharacterEncoding = reader.getEncoding();
    return defaultCharacterEncoding;
   }
}
```